# Horizontal Scrollbar showing in navigation media queries

Tags: css, media

I am tired and didn't find any solution of how to get rid of this issue. First check the screenshot over here

http://i.gyazo.com/6a37d495512524e476987083a1eca9d4.png

Now here is the code

```
<nav class="main-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

@media only screen and (min-width:240px) and (max-width:767px){
    .main-header .logo{
        float: none;
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        width: 40%;
    }

    .main-header .main-nav {
        width: 100%;
        float: none;
        display: block;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

    .main-header .main-nav ul{
        float: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .main-nav ul li{
        float: none;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a{
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #cccccc;
    }

    .main-nav li:last-child a{
        border:0;
    }

    .main-nav ul li a:hover, .main-nav ul li a.active{
        border:0;
        background: #e7e5e2;
        padding: 10px 20px;

}
}
```

This is the first time when i am facing such issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you could check which element is causing the overflow on your right side and adapt that. But from the code you provided it's hard to exactly reproduce what we see in your screenshot. And when you don't need the scrollbar (so when there is no actual content on the right side) you can simply hide the scrollbar by adding this CSS to the element which is causing your scrollbar: `overflow-x: hidden;`